# Show unique values of a query result that uses UNION ( union returns two columns, I want to show unique values from one column)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables shared_news and saved_news , both of them have link, title and timestamp column. I want to combine link and title of both the table and filter unique values based on link column and ORDER BY timestamp. I need both link and title for showing in my app.

When I use ,

```
SELECT link, title, timestamp FROM saved_news UNION SELECT link, 
title, timestamp FROM shared_news ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

I am getting duplicate values. I tried many posts in stackoverflow and elsewhere in internet but could not do it. I need your help please.

Here is a screen shot on what is now and what I'm expecting.

http://snpy.in/d2OiQO

Comment: You can use `SELECT DISTINCT` on the results of the above as a subquery to get only unique rows.

Comment: tried to use that but not able to . Will you mind to help me with the actual query to get the result.

Comment: They are technically not duplicates, because `timestamp` has different values.

Comment: But it's very normal to have duplicate rows, after being able to see the picture, I realized that `timestamp` values are not unique for unique values of `link` and `title`.

Comment: The image you posted shows what you get now but not your expected results. Do you want all 3 columns, 2 of them or just 1? And when you say *ORDER BY timestamp* in the case of the duplicates which of the 2 timestamps will be used?

Comment: hi forpas, I want no content to duplicate in link column.

Comment: please re-read the last three comments above. **Or**, I'd like to ask that are you only considering date part of the timestamp column ..? ( Whenever you do so, do you have still duplicate rows ? )

Comment: I'm really sorry if I'm not able to communicate properly. I need to consider full timestamp with date & time because my goal is to show the latest news based on timestamp by getting news links from both shared_news and saved_news table. If I consider only date of part of timestamp also I'm getting duplicates. I don't want to see duplicate row in links column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are interested only in the column `link` to be unique.
So after the `UNION` use `group by link` and aggregate the other columns:

```
select t.link, max(t.title) title, max(t.timestamp) timestamp
from (
  select link, title, timestamp from saved_news 
  union 
  select link, title, timestamp from shared_news 
) t
group by t.link
order by timestamp desc
```

Answer (score 1):

If the duplicate values are only between tables rather than within a table, then the most efficient method is probably:

```
select san.link, san.title, san.timestamp 
from saved_news san
union all
select shn.link, shn.title, shn.timestamp 
from shared_news shn
where not exists (select 1
                  from saved_news san
                  where san.link = shn.link
                 );
```

And you want an index on `saved_news(link)`.

This should be much faster than methods that use `union`, `select distinct`, or `group by`.

Comment: Working great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @PradeepBehera . . . Do you find that it is faster than other solutions?

Comment: Gordon Linoff query time - 6 total, Query took 0.0008 seconds. forpas query time - 6 total, Query took 0.0009 seconds. Gordon's query executes little faster, this is small data, for huge data it may prove to be more faster.

Comment: `where not exists (..)` scales with *O(n log(n))* (assuming equal table size). `union`, `distinct` and `group by` all scale with *O(n log(n))*. And you still need  `ORDER BY timestamp`, which is again *O(n log(n))*. The constant factor might be smaller with your query - or not. I couldn't say which method is faster without tests.

Comment: @PradeepBehera . . . You cannot trust times when they are so small.  The issue is scaling.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel . . . `GROUP BY` is typically implementing using sorting algorithms that generally require reading and writing the data multiple times.  The use of an index with a correlated subquery is only reading data and indexes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've tested your query (#1), forpas' query (#2) and forpas' query with UNION ALL (#3). Data set 1 (D1): two tables 75K rows each with 100K unique links (50K duplicates). Data set 2 (D2): 750K rows per table, 1M unique links. Results: D1:{#1:110ms, #2:210ms, #3:150ms}; D2:{#1:6.5s, #2:20s, #3:11s}. So your query is indeed faster. But "**much** faster" is something different. #1 and #3 seem to scale (almost) equally.

Answer (score 0):

Try this please eventually you have Spaces leading or trailing

```
SELECT TRIM(link), TRIM(title), TRIM(timestamp) timestamp FROM saved_news 
 UNION DISTINCT 
SELECT TRIM(link), TRIM(title), TRIM(timestamp) timestamp FROM shared_news 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response nbk, but it gives duplicate. your query gives distinct values from shared_news but same value may be there in saved_news table. I want distinct values in link column after the UNION.

Comment: I changed it , so that it trims your data in case there are spaces preventing the destinct to work

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'timestamp' in 'order clause'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure about the goal but this should get you all link & titles with no duplicates

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT a.link, a.title FROM (
    SELECT link, title, timestamp FROM saved_news ORDER BY timestamp DESC UNION 
    SELECT link, title, timestamp FROM shared_news ORDER BY timestamp DESC
) as a;
```

or if you need them with timestamps, but only from the table's row in which it first appears:

```sql
SELECT a.link, a.title, a.timestamp FROM (
    SELECT link, title, timestamp FROM saved_news ORDER BY timestamp DESC UNION 
    SELECT link, title, timestamp FROM shared_news ORDER BY timestamp DESC
) as a GROUP BY a.link, a.title;
```

not 100% on the placement of that order by.

Comment: #1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY
for both the query